# Can't connect to WebDriver. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444 (codeceptjs )

Tags: codeceptjs

[image]

I've done configuration by using https://codecept.io/quickstart this tutorial and try to run `npx codeceptjs run --steps` this command , and then I get this issue . I use for this ubuntu wsl system on windows 10 . Why do this happens ? If you need more information , pls let me know !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to use the WebDriver helper.
This needs a selenium server running.

The easiest is to install it via `npx selenium-standalone install` and then to run it via `npx selenium-standalone start`. In a new command line window run `npx codeceptjs run --steps` again.

Answer (score 0):

Just stand up a Selenium server running on port `4444`.
e.g.,

> docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name=selenium --rm -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome

More info can be found here: https://codecept.io/quickstart-webdriver